# XML document structure must start and end within the same entity

Tags: android, xml

I'm quite a newbie for the eclipse, and I'm just started to write some code(actually it's just copy and paste from the website)
can anyone help me about this???
*the error is appear on the last line

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

    </ToggleButton>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

    </ToggleButton>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to close the LinearLayout tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

    </ToggleButton>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

XML document structure must start and end within the same entity, as you can see, there's a < ToggleButton .... > and a < /ToggleButton > which make a pair, but < LinearLayout .... > still needs something to make a pair.

I think it's better for you to have a better understanding of XML, it's quite easy and useful.here's a good tutorial:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/XML_Introduction

Comment: Everything was hard for a newbie xD Thanks^^

Comment: Please [avoid referencing w3schools](http://w3fools.com/). Instead, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/XML_Introduction) has a good introduction to XML.